# Check if string is empty inside a placeholder tag?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to check if a string is empty inside a tag? I have this input field and it has a placeholder tag. I need to check if the variable which goes inside placeholder tag is empty.

```
<input type="text" placeholder={{searchText}}>
```

How can I check if searchText is empty and render something else while it is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{ searchText || 'searchText Is Empty'}}">
```

Comment: Sorry.. my fault Try:

`<input type="text" placeholder="{{ searchText || 'searchText Is Empty'}}">`

Answer (score 0):

You can write any expression into your placeholder, then you could do something as :

```
<input type="text" placeholder={{searchText && searchText.length ? searchText : 'other text' }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using ternary operator.

```
   condition ? expr1 : expr2


 <input type="text" placeholder="{{searchText.trim() !='' ? searchText : 'some other text' }}">
```